# Document ready en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente problema:

```
app.controller('EOGController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.result = "primero";

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        loadQuantiles();
    });

    var loadQuantiles = function () {   
        console.log("entro");
        $scope.result = "ultimo";
        console.log("salio");
    }
}]);

index.html

<div class="container" ng-controller="EOGController">
    {{result}}  <!-- <- cuyo valor siempre es primero -->
</div>
```

¿Por qué no cambia de

PD: los `console.logs()` si salen correctamente en la consola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estas interrumpiendo el ciclo de vida de las funciones en AngularJS, al usar el evento ready, por lo que no deberías de usarlo de esa forma. Al momento que AngularJS ejecuta el controlador es por que ya se puede trabajar con el DOM, en caso de que necesites algo como esto, simplemente llama a la función:

```
$scope.$digest()
```

para que avise a AngularJS que las variables sobre el $scope tienen cambios, solo que ten en cuenta que no es la manera correcta.
[Ejemplo funcionando en codepen](http://codepen.io/uriel_tzel/pen/aBWMrQ)